# Does RDP consume my internet data

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop, remote, protocol

I want to ask that what if I download 1 gig file inside the RDP and the I want to copy the file to my local system so will it consum my 1 gig internet or no it's just copy and paste
Hope you answer it well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you download a file in an RDP session, that machine's internet is used to download the file.

When you then transfer it from that machine to your machine, your machine's internet is used to receive the file and the other machine's internet is used to send the file. This assumes remote access.

If the machine is local to you, then that machines internet is used to get the file (but that would be your internet - local to you) and then just file copy to get to your machine.

Lots of file movement. Can you download the file directly ?  Then the download / transfer will only be occurring once.

You need to be clear if the machine you are RDP'ing to is local to you or remote because a remote machine will result in more Internet traffic as I assumed at the beginning and outlined.